# jQuery - get current text selection within input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several input boxes with the same class name. I want to be able to get the currently highlighted text and know exactly which input box that text is in. My current method is as so:

```
 $(document).on("mouseup", ".element", function(){
    var text = "";
    var activeEl = document.activeElement;
    var activeElTagName = activeEl ? activeEl.tagName.toLowerCase() : null;
    if (
    (activeElTagName == "textarea") || (activeElTagName == "input" &&
    /^(?:text|search|password|tel|url)$/i.test(activeEl.type)) &&
    (typeof activeEl.selectionStart == "number")
    ) {
        text = activeEl.value.slice(activeEl.selectionStart, activeEl.selectionEnd);
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
   }
});
```

This gives me the current text selection and I can call `$(this)` to access the element that the highlighted text is in.

The problem with my current method however, is that if you begin the click and then drag outside the text box, say just outside the left edge of the text box, you'll have highlighted text within the box but the event will not register, since the mouse click ended outside the scope of the input field. How can I remedy this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind more than one event to a handler.
So just bind `mouseleave` too!

```
$(document).on("mouseup mouseleave", ".element", function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an onselect event on the input boxes. When you select the text, an onselect event is reigistered. Afterwards, you can find the starting point of the highlighted text and the ending point of the highlighted text.

See snippet below

```js
$(".boxes").on('select', function() {
  if (window.getSelection) {
    text = window.getSelection().toString();
    var start_index = this.selectionStart;
    var end_index = this.selectionEnd;
    console.log(this.value.substr(start_index, end_index));
  }
}) //end mouseover
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="in1" class="boxes">
<input id="in1" class="boxes">
<input id="in1" class="boxes">
<input id="in1" class="boxes">
<input id="in1" class="boxes">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable like `isMouseDown` outside of the scope of the event handler like so:

```
var isMouseDown = false;

$(document).on("mousedown", ".element", function(){
  isMouseDown = true;
});

$(document).on("mouseup", document, function(){
  if (isMouseDown) {
    var text = "";
    var activeEl = document.activeElement;
    var activeElTagName = activeEl ? activeEl.tagName.toLowerCase() : null;
    if (
    (activeElTagName == "textarea") || (activeElTagName == "input" &&
    /^(?:text|search|password|tel|url)$/i.test(activeEl.type)) &&
    (typeof activeEl.selectionStart == "number")
    ) {
        text = activeEl.value.slice(activeEl.selectionStart, activeEl.selectionEnd);
    } else if (window.getSelection()) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    }
  }
  isMouseDown = false;
});
```